# Save image from URL to SQLITE Database using AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite

i am using this method urlToImageBLOB() to convert the inserted image url into byte[], but it is showing a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error because this method will not work after AndroidStudio 3.0.0 update. While dealing with this error it asks me to change conversion inside an AsyncTask class.
I'm stuck in this I need to store the image from URL given by webservice into database and I need to retrieve it from database and need to set into the imageview.

```
public static byte[] urlToImageBLOB(String url) throws IOException {
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    entity = null;
    httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        entity = response.getEntity();
    }
    return EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
}
```

Please show me how to add the image byte[] into database and fetch from database as well as how to set into the imageView.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884058/sqlite-is-it-possible-to-insert-a-blob-via-insert-statement

Comment: this way is not supported after android studio update of 3.0.0, we need to use asynctask for the same